# Practical but pretty basic "real world" statistics problem

Tags: probability

It was suggested that this forum may be quite helpful. My most humble apologies if I am somehow not posting in the right place!

My bosses asked *me* (I am not a statistician) how many letters have to be mailed out in a certain county in order to see if the response rate for the whole list is likely to be at least 10%?

I have no training in statistics and am completely confused at this point. Here are the relevant numbers that should be necessary to arrive at an answer, though:

- The county has 1,532 locations that *could* be mailed.
- My bosses would like to be a minimum of 80% sure.
- The response rate of the letter is generally 10% anywhere in the United States (I'm not sure if this number is relevant or not).

How many letters must be sent to determine with about 80% confidence that the whole (1,532) list will be as responsive as normal (10%)?

I'd be delighted to to add whatever numbers or answers I might have unintentionally left out.

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem with the way the question is asked. Sending more letters will not increase the rate of response, so “how many letters do we have to send to be 80% sure that the response will be 10%” can’t be what is truly sought. As @asdf points out, given an effect size like 5%, we can ask how many letters do we need to send to be 80% sure the answer is 15% rather than the null-hypothetical 10%, based on something like a 95% confidence interval around 10%. ( He says its 150. Sounds plausible to me.) So please verify the exact question you mean to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the actual response rate itself. If it is very far from 10%, you will need fewer. If it is 9,99999999%, your grandchildren would be sending letters without still finding a significant difference.

As a reference, if the response rate was close 15%, you would find out after about 150 letters sent